# Master page to Layout in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have to user master page of MVC2 application in VS 2008 in MVC3 2010. Cananyone help me on this

Comment: We could, but where is the problem?

Comment: I suggest you read http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx. It probably has all the answers you need.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have WebForms master page (`.Master` file) with a Razor view (`.cshtml` file). If you want to use a WebForms master page you need to use a WebForms view (`.aspx` file). So simply put the `Site.Master` file in the `~/Views/Shared` folder of your ASP.NET MVC 3 application and add a WebForms view implementing it (for example `~/Views/Home/Index.aspx`).